# problem in numbering of remark, proposition, definition and theorems

Tags: numbering

I am using codes given below for article writing.

```
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{thma}{Theorem}
\renewcommand*{\thethma}{\Alph{thma}}
\newtheorem{cor}{Corollary}[section]
\newtheorem{cora}{Corollary}
\renewcommand*{\thecora}{\Alph{cora}}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{rem}[thm]{Remark}
\newtheorem{lema}{Lemma}
\renewcommand*{\thelema}{\Alph{lema}}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{propa}{Proposition}
\renewcommand*{\thepropa}{\Alph{propa}}
\newtheorem{examp}{Example}[section]
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definition}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
```

But in output my required numbering is correct but remark and propositions are not in bold letters, kindly suggest me the way to correct it thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Simple way is to use `\textbf{}` to change from italics to bold.

```
\newtheorem{rem}[thm]{\textbf{Remark}}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{\textbf{Proposition}}
```

Or you can add `amsthm` package in your preamble. This package allows you to customize the theorem style. An example is shown below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{boldremark}
    {} % space above
    {} % space below
    {}  % body font
    {}          % indent amount
    {\bfseries} % theorem head font
    {.}         % punctuation after theorem head
    {.5em}      % space after theorem head
    {}          % theorem hed spec. (empty = "normal")
% 
%     
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}
% 
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{dfn}{Definition}
% 
\theoremstyle{boldremark}
\newtheorem{rmk}{Remark}

\begin{document}

\begin{rmk}
    It is well known that\[1+1=2\mbox{.}\]
\end{rmk}
Some text after the remark.

% 

\begin{prop}
 It is well known that\[1+1=2\mbox{.}\]
\end{prop}
\end{document}
```

[image: Remark in bold letters]

Comment: ok got it thanks